# KafkaConsumer resume partition cannot continue to receive uncommitted messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using one topic, one partition, one consumer, Kafka client version is 0.10.

I got two different results:

1. If I [paused](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection)) partition first, then to produce a message and to invoke [resume](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#resume(java.util.Collection)) method. KafkaConsumer can poll the uncommitted message successfully.
2. But If I produced message first and didn't commit its offset, then to pause the partition, after several seconds, to invoke the resume method.  KafkaConsumer would not receive the uncommitted message. I checked it on Kafka server using `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`, it shows `LOG-END-OFFSET minus CURRENT-OFFSET = LAG = 1`.

I have been trying to figure out it for two days, I repeated such tests a lot of times, the results are always like so. I need some suggestion or someone can tell me its Kafka's original mechanism.

Comment: 0.10 is now pretty old, have you tried with a more recent version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your observation#2, if you restart the application, it will supply you all records from the un-committed offset, i.e. the missing record and if your consumer again does not commit, it will be sent again when application registers consumer with Kafka upon restart. It is expected.

Assuming you are using `consumer.poll()` which creates a hybrid-streaming interface i.e. if accumulates data coming into Kafka for the `duration` mentioned and provides it to the consumer for processing once the duration is finished. This continuous accumulation happens in the backend and is not dependent on whether you have committed offset or not.

[KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

> The position of the consumer gives the offset of the next record that
>   will be given out. It will be one larger than the highest offset the
>   consumer has seen in that partition. It automatically advances every
>   time the consumer receives messages in a call to poll(long).

Comment: Thank you, it explains clear. That’s my big blind spot. It seems that I can handle #2 by using seek method of KafkaConsumer.